# cors - Response for preflight is invalid (redirect) - redux

Tags: reactjs, cors, redux, fetch

I have action

```
export function searchInWiki(search) {
const myRequest = new Request(API_URL + search);
const myInit = {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
   'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'DELETE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '1728000'
  }
};

return dispatch => fetch(myRequest, myInit)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => dispatch(getResults(json)))
}
```

But I keep getting error "Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)". Could you please give my any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your server is responding with a redirect when you're making a CORS preflight request. It shouldn't do that. I've seen that happen before where it's redirecting as reaction to an authorization failure. The way we handled that was to check if the request method equals `OPTIONS` then immediately just end the response with status code 200.

Comment: Authorization? strange. I based on starter kit https://redux-minimal.js.org/ and I did not mess a lot there. Just installed redux-thunk. Server here does not include any authorization... But this kit is created for readux-sagas, not thunk - maybe there could be something messing in cors?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the `credentials` option:

> credentials: 'same-origin', // include, same-origin, *omit

Other than that, I don't understand why are you sending headers from the browser that are supposed to be filled by the server instead. I'm talking about all these CORS headers. Check the [docs on using `fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) but specially [on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), which explain which are the headers allowed in a CORS request:

> Apart from the headers set automatically by the user agent (for
>   example, Connection, User-Agent, or any of the other headers with
>   names defined in the Fetch spec as a “forbidden header name”), the
>   only headers which are allowed to be manually set are those which the
>   Fetch spec defines as being a “CORS-safelisted request-header”, which
>   are:
>
> ```
> Accept
> Accept-Language
> Content-Language
> Content-Type (but note the additional requirements below)
> Last-Event-ID
> DPR
> Save-Data
> Viewport-Width
> Width
> ```